# Change referencing style from APA to IEEE in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I have written a document with APA references. Now I decided to apply IEEE references instead of APA. How can I change the APA references style of my document to the IEEE style.

Comment: [APA, MLA, Chicago – automatically format bibliographies](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apa-mla-chicago-%E2%80%93-automatically-format-bibliographies-405c207c-7070-42fa-91e7-eaf064b14dbb), [Create Custom Bibliography Styles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/create-custom-bibliography-styles)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the "Insert Citation" button? If you did, then look on the References ribbon for Style. Click and change the style from APA to IEEE.

(If you didn't use the "Insert Citation" feature of Word, then please edit your question to include a sample of your APA references.)